# Fatal error - cannot execute Fortran code in Eclipse compiler

Tags: eclipse, fortran, ide

The other night compiling Fortran in Eclipse was working for me, however, today I have been receiving this error:

> gfortran: fatal error: cannot execute 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.

It script builds but I would get the error:

> Binary not found

Any idea on what I can do?

I cannot configure a build neither as no project can be searched for.